# How to get Device Data from Braintree gateway in Flutter Android Side?

Tags: android, flutter, braintree, braintree-data

I need Device Data for Fraud Detection while sending Credit Card payment method bounce to my server but I don't find any other way for getting Device Data.
Im not using dropin for credit card payment method bounce, I'm using flutter_braintree: ^2.0.0 BraintreeCreditCardRequest and then tokenizeCreditCard.

```
final reqCard = BraintreeCreditCardRequest(
cardNumber: cardNumber.value.text,
expirationMonth: expMonth.value.text,
expirationYear: expYear.value.text,
cvv: cardCVV.value.text,
);


BraintreePaymentMethodNonce result = await Braintree.tokenizeCreditCard(
    Constant.sandBoxTokenizationKey,
    reqCard,
  );
```

The result not include device data.

Is there any way to collect Device data on Android side?